# Changing the search rule on Tibco Spotfire for column search

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I was wondering if there is a way to change the search rule?

I am working on Tibco Spotfire and Tibco Clarity shows that you can change the rule to incorporate regex.

I have three part numbers that are the same, with the only difference is an added prefix to the part number to identify the unique customers.

I want to change the filter rules such that I don't have to add a regex * to the prefix to bring up all three when I'm using the filter.